# What does "Deprecated. Instead, use composability." mean in Reactjs Material-UI menuItems?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am taking back a project that has been made with an older version of react and I am updating this project, but I am receiving console errors first.

**Error** :

> bundle.js:6263 Warning: "menuItems" property of "LeftNav" has been deprecated.
>   Instead, use composability.

My first approach was to search the Material-UI documentation and regarding "Left Nav" -> menuItems, I found the explanation to be the same message as the one displayed in the console.

As, I am not familiar with react and I am unable to understand what "composability" means here.

Reacts documentation talks about [Multiple Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html), but I can only see Html treatment for Multiple Object.

**My code** :

```
var menuItems = [
    { route: '/', text: 'Home' },
    { type: 'SUBHEADER', text: 'Connect' },
    { route: '/categories', text: 'Categories' },
    { route: '/icons', text: 'Icons'},
];
```

which is **not** within a class and then, in the render function:

```
    <LeftNav ref="leftNav"
             docked={false}
             style={{opacity: '0.9'}}
             menuItems={menuItems}
             onChange={this.leftNavOnChange}
     />
```

Has anyone come across with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `children` instead of `menuItems`.

For example:

```
<LeftNav>
    <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
</LeftNav>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I am learning more on my side about react, but how do you keep the root / text then? Do you have to write everything in an other object or collect it as if it was "json"?

Comment: @JayCee Now you need manualy pass all elements which should be in LeftNav. 
You can use `menuItems.map` to render multiple MenuItem and set props which you need. 
It was done because some people need to pass custom content inside LeftNav, not only MenuItem.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One last question, is it possible to keep the style it had or have I to rewrite it?